# Jasmine & Angular: Mocking nested methods of Class under Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Honored community...

I am facing the following problem, which feels simple, but I can't find a solution...

I am testing a Controller-Class in Angular. It is legacy code with tons of dependency and **I just want to write a unit test *without* mocking all the dependencies**.

I am looking for a solution to **mock nested functions**, i.e. I call a method, and expect that the nested method was successfully called, **without** actually calling it.

A sample...

**my-controller.ts**

```
export class MyController {

   constructor () {}
   public init() {
      /* doStuff */
      this.initializeMyObject();
   }

   private initializeMyObject(): void {
     /*  doOtherStuff  */
   }
}
```

**my-controller.spec.ts**

```
describe('MyController', () => {
  let controller: MyController;

  configureTestSuite(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [/*.. module imports ..*/],
      providers: [ MyController ],
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    controller = TestBed.get(MyController);
  });

  it('completion should be called', () => {
    // arrange
    spyOn(controller, 'initializeMyObject');

    // act
    controller.init();

    // assert
    expect(controller.initializeMyObject).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

I know that we usually do not mock methods of the Class being tested, but I know from other programming languages like Java that it works, and I am just curious how to do it (in addition to the fact, that mocking all nested dependcies would be a total overhead...).

I've read something about `jasmine.createSpyObj` but I doubt that the solution will be something like  `jasmine.createSpyObj('this', ['initializeMyObject'])`, please correct me if I am wrong.

(This is not part of the answer I am looking for, but if there exist some third party libs, I will be glad to have a recommendation and follow up.)

Help will be appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to mock individual class methods with Jasmine. Here are a few examples.

When a method has no return value (`void` return type).

```
spyOn(object, 'method-name').and.callFake(() => null);
```

When the method should return a given value.

```
spyOn(object, 'method-name').and.returnValue(value);
```

When the method accepts parameter and should return a computed value based on them.

```
spyOn(object, 'method-name').and.callFake((p1, p2) => {
    // compute value
    return value;
});
```

Comment: but how can I test if the method was really called?
how to verify: ```expect(object.method-name).toHaveBeenCalled()```?

Comment: `expect(object.method-name).toHaveBeenCalled()` is just fine

Comment: Can you please share the full content of the `MyController.init` and `MyController.initializeMyObject` methods? Maybe you perform some asynchronous work in there.

Comment: Please also consider this answer since you're spying on a private method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734437/2358409

Comment: I do have an asychronos function in there, but this one is mocked. and I receive a console.log output a line before ```initializeMyObject``` is called, so it definitely gets there.

```spyOn<any>``` or ```MyController.prototype``` are not successfull either

Comment: Try to wrap your test with `fakeAsync`: https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync

Comment: as mentioned above, I don't think that the problem is in the async function, since as mentioned it is stubbed.. the method directly resolves. and i am getting to the ```then``` case where my ```initializeMyController``` is